# How to remove certain meta data from customer emails (Woocommerce)?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have products that have a non-required field to upload a file.
After checkout, both admin and customer get an email about the order.
If an item has a file "attached" to it, the mail includes a preview image and a link to the file on my shop server. I would like to remove these two but not the filename from the customer's email. As far as I have seen, there is a hook to add things to what is being shown in mails. But how can I remove data?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'action_woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 10 , 4 );

function action_woocommerce_order_item_meta_start( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {
    // only email notifications
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url() ) return; 
    
    $metadata = $item['item_meta'];

    // ???
}
```

The part of the mail looks like this:

[image: screenshot of email]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value', 'change_order_item_meta_value', 20, 3 );

/**
 * Changing a meta value
 * @param  string        $value  The meta value
 * @param  WC_Meta_Data  $meta   The meta object
 * @param  WC_Order_Item $item   The order item object
 * @return string        The title
 */
function change_order_item_meta_value( $value, $meta, $item ) {
    // only email notifications
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url() ) return;
 
    // By using $meta-key we are sure we have the correct one.
    if (strstr($meta->key, "Druckvorlage")) {
        $value = strip_tags($value);
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Here is a good post on working with order item meta data: https://www.ibenic.com/manage-order-item-meta-woocommerce/

Comment: Good, but replace `if ( is_wc_endpoint_url() ) return;` with `if ( is_admin() || is_wc_endpoint_url() ) return $value;` 
because currently you don't return any value in that particular if condition, which will throw errors in certain circumstances. 
This is not necessary with an action hook, but it is with a **filter** hook.